# Run scalable Service in GKE with fixed Domain and Port

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloudflare

I've a shipped app where a URL is hardcoded "upload.mydomain.io:123123/myRoute".

This DNS points to an VM where an NGINX distributes the traffic to services. 
Now I need to put a highly scalable service in front of the VM, WITHOUT having the possibility to change the hardcoded URL. I've tried so far:

- Cloud Functions
- App Engine
- Cloud Run
- My own Kubernetes Cluster.

As an DNS Distributer I use Cloudflare, where I also tried to do something with Page Rules.

Functions -> No Domain in EU

Cloud Run -> Only Port 80

App Engine -> Only Port 8080

Kubernetes Ingress -> I can put my Domain on, also with the port as Service port, but then in the URL the port is gone

This is my Kubernetes Manifest:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: myApp-api
  name: myApp-api
spec:
  replicas: 3
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: myApp-api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myApp-api
        env:
        - name: NODE_ENV
          value: production
        image: eu.gcr.io/myApp-123/myApp-api:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 21337
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}


---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: myApp-api-service
  name: myApp-api-service
spec:
  ports:
  - name: myApp-api-port
    port: 21337
    targetPort: 21337
  selector:
    app: myApp-api
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer: {}

---

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myApp-api-ingress
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - upload.myDomain.io
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: upload.myDomain.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: myApp-api-service
          servicePort: myApp-api-port
```

Is it possible somehow to create this route with some service?

Comment: You might want to try asking this on ServerFault. https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using Kubernetes service of type Loadbalancer.

For example

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 123123
      targetPort: 8000
```

Refer: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/service &
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/#loadbalancer

Comment: And then, map your DNS to loadbalancer IP.

Comment: I tried that, but then the Port in the URL is obsolete. It would be upload.mydomain.io, but without Port

Comment: could you please show the load balancer config, plus is it working with `upload.mydomain.io:123123`?

Comment: I think you are missing something, could you please add the manifest files that you are using to deploy? https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps

Comment: Could you please add a new dns entry pointing to the load balancer ip and test. For example point `newupload.mydomain.io`. Ingress is not required as we are already exposing the service with a Loadbalancer